# Computing the resolvent of a rank one projector

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

I'm reading through [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1999-351-07/S0002-9947-99-02023-1/S0002-9947-99-02023-1.pdf) in dynamical systems, that's using a bit of perturbation theory and operator theory. The authors make the following claim:

> Now, since $P_0$ is a projection of rank one, it is easy to compute explicitly its resolvent, namely
> $$ R_0(ζ) = (P_0 − ζ)^{−1} = \frac{P_0}{1−ζ} − \frac{I−P_0}{ζ} $$

I have no background in operator theory, but I've skimmed through Kato's *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators* and done a quick Google search and it's not at all obvious to me where this formula comes from. Does anyone have a source for the resolvent of a rank one projection?

Comment: Well, does $(P_{0} - \zeta)^{-1} (P_{0} - \zeta) = \text{Id}$?

Comment: @PeterMorfe *sigh* yep, thanks, that makes perfect sense, I'm an idiot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're not an idiot.  It still leaves the question: how to guess such a formula?

Comment: @PeterMorfe Isn't it the spectral decomposition (eigenvalues 1 & 0)? Or, "partial fraction decomposition of the resolvent"?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96348/eigenvalues-of-projector-matrix

Comment: More generally one has the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), though this is more properly a matrix identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometric series expansions gives you what you want, at least for $|\zeta| > 1$:
\begin{align}
    (P_0-\zeta I)^{-1}
    &=\left(\zeta\left(\frac{1}{\zeta}P_0-I\right)\right)^{-1} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(I-\frac{1}{\zeta}P_0\right)^{-1} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(I+\frac{1}{\zeta}P_0+\frac{1}{\zeta^2}P_0^2+\frac{1}{\zeta^3}P_0^3+\cdots\right) \\
   &= -\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(I+\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(1+\frac{1}{\zeta}+\frac{1}{\zeta^2}+\cdots \right)P_0\right) \\
   &= -\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(I+\frac{1}{\zeta}\frac{1}{1-1/\zeta}P_0\right) \\
   &= -\frac{1}{\zeta}\left(I+\frac{1}{\zeta-1}P_0\right) \\
   &=-\frac{1}{\zeta}I-\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-1}-\frac{1}{\zeta}\right)P_0 \\
   &=-\frac{1}{\zeta}(I-P_0)-\frac{1}{\zeta-1}P_0.
\end{align}
Then you can check that the right-hand side is the inverse for *all* $\zeta\ne 0,1$.

Comment: Is it used at some point that $P_0$ is a rank-one projector, or is it sufficient with the condition $P_0^2=P_0$ on its domain of definition?

Comment: @AlanGarbarz : After deriving the expression, I indicated that you can check that the expression works if you only assume $P_0^2=P_0$.

Answer (score 0):

For nonzero $a,b$,
$$(aP + b(I-P))^{-1} = \frac{P}{a} + \frac{I-P}{b} .$$
Setting $a = 1-\zeta$ and $b = -\zeta$ gives the result.